# `allow_any_instance_of` mock not working in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My mock is only working when it's in the before block shown below.  This is just my quick and dirty representation of my problem.  Literally when I move the line from the before block to the `does not quack` assertion, it stops mocking :(

```
describe 'Ducks', type: :feature do
  before do
    ...
    allow_any_instance_of(Duck).to receive(:quack).and_return('bark!')
    visit animal_farm_path
  end

  context 'is an odd duck'
    it 'does not quack' do
      expect(Duck.new.quack).to eq('bark!')
    end
  end
end
```

I want it here, but it doesn't work:

```
describe 'Ducks', type: :feature do
  before do
    ...
    visit animal_farm_path
  end

  context 'is an odd duck'
    it 'does not quack' do
      allow_any_instance_of(Duck).to receive(:quack).and_return('bark!')
      expect(Duck.new.quack).to eq('bark!')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Can you do expect after the call `Duck.new.quack` ?

Comment: No.  Just when my `quack` method gets called in the top example, it returns `bark!`, but it does not when the `allow_any_instance_of(Duck)...` is moved into the `it` block.

Comment: So are you getting any error ?

Comment: I notice you're calling `Duck.new.quack` twice. I don't think that's problem, but could you try remove the second call to help narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: @AndyWaite That's the problem, you got it right!

Comment: Sorry guys, I figured it out.  My question was poorly example-ized.  I forgot that it was a feature spec and visiting the page is was engages the method call.  Stay tuned for the solution.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed it was a feature spec. In general you wouldn't stub or mock anything in that type of test.

Comment: I agree, but it's what our team is working on.  We were getting from terrible tests, to 'okay' tests, and in the future we will get proper unit, controller, and feature specs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My bad.  The original question was poorly written.  Visiting the page is what makes the `#quack` call.  The mocks must always be done before you do whatever it is that engages the method call. So this was my solution

```
describe 'Ducks', type: :feature do
  before do
    ...
  end

  context 'is an odd duck'
    it 'does not quack' do
      allow_any_instance_of(Duck).to receive(:quack).and_return('bark!')
      visit animal_farm_path

      # In this crude example, the page prints out the animals sound
      expect(page).to have_text('bark!')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Andy: Stack overflow makes me wait 2 days before doing so.  Give me time, man! ;)

Comment: Wow, I think you have completely solved my bafflement over intermittent success with allow_any_instance_of.